# Download a file to local computer through link on other website

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

The code below is in a function called from a view. The website `www.example.com` called below is not owned by me.

```
br = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(
soup_config={'features': 'lxml'},
raise_on_404=True,
user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13"
)
br.open('http://www.example.com/Login.aspx')
br.select_form('form[id=Login]')
br["txtLogin"] = user_id
br['txtpwd'] = password
x = br.submit_selected("cmdLogin")
x = br.open('http://www.example.com/frmClientView.aspx')
br.select_form('form[id=aspnetForm]')
br["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cmbSearch"] = "Client Code"
submit_response = br.submit_selected()
soup = BeautifulSoup(submit_response.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.find(id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdDetail")
```

The `table` has some href links to download files.The files are downloaded on the server. Is there some way to download the linked files on the local computer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You detect the `href`s (with for example a search), and then you iterate over that list, and make extra request to download.

Comment: Download is on the server. I want the file saved to local computer.